# PSQL 9.3 ident authentication error on Fedora 21

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ident

[PSGQL 9.3, Fedora 21, Rails 4.2.0]

When I run any rails db command (rake db:migrate, rake db:create, etc), this error happen:

```
[dguedes@localhost clean_forum]$ rake db:create
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "dguedes"
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"UTF8", "database"=>"forum_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"dguedes", "password"=>"randompass", "host"=>"localhost"}
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "dguedes"
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails4.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/dguedes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"forum_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"dguedes", "password"=>"randompass", "host"=>"localhost"}
```

In postgres, I already created the role 'dguedes' with the correct password, and granted all privileges. For example:

```
bash-4.3$ psql -d forum_development -U dguedes
could not change directory to "/home/dguedes/Desktop/forum/clean_forum": Permission denied
Password for user dguedes: 
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help.

forum_development=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 dguedes   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

forum_development=#
```

That shows that my role already have all the permissions.

My ph_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

I restarted the server with the command 'systemctl stop postgresql-9.3' and 
'systemctl start postgresql-9.3', but nothing happened.

And, finally, my 'database.yml' file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: UTF8
  database: forum_development
  pool: 5
  username: dguedes
  password: randompass
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: forum_test
  pool: 5
  username: dguedes
  password: randompass
  host: localhost
```

So, I can't figure the problem. I already try'd to reinstall postgre to clean everything but just don't worked. What looks wrong?

Comment: Try to disable SElinux .. as root "setenforce 0"

Comment: Hmmm I will try, thanks Pavel (sorry for taking too long to post a feedback). . I managed to make the db pass using 'permit' in every method after a new clean installation. Any other solution will be... appreciated.

Comment: Disabling SELinux is just temporary solution, if it help, you know so you have to fix your SElinux configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
>   "encoding"=>"UTF8", "database"=>"forum_development", "pool"=>5,
>   "username"=>"dguedes", "password"=>"XXXXXXX", "host"=>"localhost"}
>   FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "dguedes"

You have ident configuration configured for all users on IP address localhost this meaus if you are not operating system user accout `dguedes` you cannot connect to postgresql as user postgresql username `dguedes`.

> psql -d forum_development -U dguedes

here you connect via the "local" interface  ( "local" is not the same as "localhost" ). Local is a *unix domain socket* (address `/var/run/postgresql/5432` or something like that)  this interface has md5 authentication for all users so anyone wantinng to connect as `dguedes` is asked for a password.

if you want to use this interface from you application the connection parameters string should not have host specified:

```
 {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"UTF8", "database"=>"forum_development",
  "pool"=>5, "username"=>"dguedes", "password"=>"XXXXXXX" }
```

or optionally host should be specified explicitly empty, or NULL.

```
  ,"host"=>""
```

I see two other problems.

You expose your password in you log file above, so now would be a good time to change it.

In pg_hba.conf have disabled ident for the local postgres user. that's used by some maintenance tasks and should be re-enabled.

Comment: Thanks Jasen. This explains why it always asked my pass, and why sometimes it asks my pass when I try to login as postgres and sometimes don't. I can't try this NOW because I'm in a different ambient, but i'll asap.

Comment: You, sir, is a master. Thanks. (the blank host solved).